# É possível ter multiplas conexões em um único socket?

Tags: php, socket

O seguinte código, permite apenas um cliente e não vários no mesmo tempo. É possível criar algo, deixa múltiplos clientes conectados?

```
$socket = socket_create( AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , SOL_TCP );

socket_bind( $socket , 'localhost' , '2000' );

socket_listen( $socket );

while ( true ) {
  $client = socket_accept( $socket );
  socket_write( $client , 'Aê! Seja bem-vindo!' );
}
```

Comment: Na verdade [tem vários sockets aí nesse código](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-accept.php). Mas isso é um estudo ou aplicação de verdade? Porque não é muito comum precisar usar sockets em PHP. Nem é a melhor linguagem para lidar com eles.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, uma das formas possíveis é com a função socket_select

http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php

(recomendo usar a documentação em inglês do php para socket, pois a em português tem quase nada)

Abaixo um exemplo

```
...
$clientes = array($socket);

//para o socket_select
$write = null;
$except = null;

while (true)
{
    $read = $clientes;

    if (socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0) < 1)
        continue;

    if (in_array($socket, $read))
    {
        $novo_cliente = socket_accept($socket);

        socket_write( $novo_cliente , 'Aê! Seja bem-vindo!' );

        //adiciona essa nova conexão ao array $clientes
        $clientes[] = $novo_cliente;
    }
}
```

Abraços